# Declaração Correta Classes Model MVC Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Comecei a usar OO a pouco tempo e em todos projetos que eu vejo na net, eu vejo a seguinte maneira de declaração.

```
public class Trabalhador
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Dependente { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Dependente { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection LicencaMedica{ get; set; }
}

public class Dependente
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Trabalhador Trabalhador { get; set; }
}

public class Ferias
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Trabalhador Trabalhador { get; set; }
}

public class LicencaMedica
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Trabalhador Trabalhador { get; set; }
}
```

Entretanto estou trabalhando em um projeto em conjunto com outros desenvolvedores, e um deles defende com unhas e dentes que as minhas classes não devem possuir o "virtual" como atributo de navegação, defende ele que as classes Dependente, Ferias e Licença pelo fato de ja terem uma ICollection em Trabalhador, nao devem possuir nenhuma chave, pois serão todas acessiveis a partir da classe trabalhador, está correto isso do ponto de vista da OO? Expus minha opiniao e falei que isso estava errado, pois estaria meio que criando uma classe Root e tudo passaria por ela sem necessidade, meio que sobrecarregando uma classe com muita responsabilidade, a abordagem dele seria a seguinte:

```
public class Trabalhador
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Dependente { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Dependente { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection LicencaMedica{ get; set; }
}

public class Dependente
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Ferias
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class LicencaMedica
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Está correto isso do ponto de vista da OO? Pra mim ter acesso a um objeto da classe filha eu devo obrigatoriamente passar pela classe pai? Segundo ele o Ninject que acusa erro no sistema, pois o fato de instanciar a classe pai e depois instanciar a classe filha segundo ele daria um loop no sistema, por isso ele arranca todas as propriedade de navegação das classes filhas.

(Nao estamos usando Entity, estamos usando ADO com SP no Banco). Tentei ser o mais especifico possivel, qual o problema de cada uma das abordagens?

Comment: Por isso que o Jon Skeet acha que as classes deveriam ser `sealed` por *default*. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6389669/221800. herança deve ser usada em última caso, quando realmente você tem uma relação *é-um*, quando isto traz benefícios. Portanto `virtual` não faz sentido se não precisar de polimorfismo. Acostume-se criar suas classes com `selead` e só o retire se achar um bom motivo para isto.

Answer (score 5):

Não que esteja errada a abordagem, mas ela é cara, computacionalmente falando.

Não havendo as propriedades das chaves estrangeiras nas relações de 1 para N faz a aplicação ter que necessariamente carregar o objeto completo, o que, mesmo com caches e tudo o mais, faz a aplicação ficar mais lenta. Para desempenho, a proposta do seu colega é péssima.

Tendo as propriedades de chaves estrangeiras na classe não contraria a proposta OO porque uma classe de entidade mapeia uma tabela do banco de dados, ou seja, todas as colunas. Está errado quando uma coluna não é mapeada apenas por ser chave estrangeira (o objeto não representa canonicamente um registro de uma tabela ou coleção do banco de dados). Além disso, o objeto pode ser carregado parcialmente quando não há necessidade de carregar as entidades relacionadas, sem qualquer perda de informação. Por exemplo: se quero apenas o nome do `Trabalhador`, não preciso carregar seus dependentes. Todas as informações sobre o trabalhador estão no objeto da classe `Trabalhador`.

Quanto ao uso de `virtual`, é importante esclarecer: `virtual` é usado para classes que possam ser derivadas. Ou seja, se por exemplo um `Dependente` for derivado para outras classes (penso  em `Conjuge` ou então `Irmao`), o objeto já não aceitaria o objeto ou a coleção. O arquiteto da solução teria que se certificar que todas as classes de entidade são imutáveis, o que sinceramente não ajuda nada no desenvolvimento.

A propósito, a modelagem não está canônica. Proponho abaixo mais uma modelagem mais dentro dos melhores padrões usados hoje para desenvolvimento em [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc):

```
public class Trabalhador
{
    // Usar apenas 'Id' como nome da propriedade pode gerar confusão na montagem
    // de sentenças comparativas, onde não esteja claro qual objeto está sendo manipulado.
    [Key]
    public int TrabalhadorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Dependente> Dependentes { get; set; }
    // Não é preciso duas ICollection iguais, então comentei a segunda.
    // ICollections são tipadas, com o nome da propriedade no plural.
    // public virtual ICollection<Dependente> Dependentes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LicencaMedica> LicencasMedicas { get; set; }
}

public class Dependente
{
    [Key]
    public int DependenteId { get; set; }
    // Ter uma chave estrangeira aqui não é errado porque cada propriedade
    // que não seja 'virtual' possui uma coluna correspondente em uma tabela no banco
    // de dados.
    public int TrabalhadorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Trabalhador Trabalhador { get; set; }
}

public class Ferias
{
    [Key]
    public int FeriasId { get; set; }
    public int TrabalhadorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Trabalhador Trabalhador { get; set; }
}

public class LicencaMedica
{
    [Key]
    public int LicencaMedicaId { get; set; }
    public int TrabalhadorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Trabalhador Trabalhador { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Aquele "Dependente" duplicado foi vacilo meu, obrigado pelo esclarecimento Cigano, pensei na mesma otica de voce, acerca do custo, pra que carregar N coisas se eu preciso apenas de uma, quanto ao atributo TrabalhadorID nas classes dependentes, eu não faço uso, já li que o entity as vezes precisa, mas como estamos usando ADO, eu prefiro instanciar a classe virtual "Trabalhador" inteira, pois nas minhas views tenho por exemplo um grid de Dependente com o nome do Trabalhador ou outra informação, portanto no meu caso esse int ID se torna desnecessario.

Comment: Então, como eu disse, sua modelagem não está canônica. Você está suprindo a necessidade da coluna através de um aspecto do seu projeto. Como a pergunta se baseia no que é correto usar, a resposta é esta mesmo. Mas fique à vontade para modelar o sistema da maneira com que achar confortável.